# Unable to structure raw query in to array

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-5

I have a resource class and a controller where I am doing some raw query like so. I have tried using `json_encode()` and `json_decode()`, but I keep getting errors.

***Json_decode**

```
Call to a member function first() on null
```

***Json_encode**

```
Call to a member function first() on string
```

***just return $test_table ***

```
Call to undefined method stdClass::toArray()
```

***TestsController.php***

```
use App\Test;
use App\Http\Resources\Test as TestResource;

public function index()
{
    $test_table = DB::table('test_table')->select('id','test_col')->paginate(10);

    return  TestResource::collection($test_table);           
}
```

***Resource**/***Test***

```
class Test extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return parent::toArray($request);
    }
}
```

The expected output should be a JSON which I can handle in the front end application something using ***GuzzleHttp*** also should be able to paginate nicely.

Comment: Where did you use `json_encode()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is related to using pagination after the select statement.. and given the fact that you are using API Resources, you could return just your desired data:

**TestsController.php**

```
use App\Test;
use App\Http\Resources\Test as TestResource;

// ...

    public function index()
    {
        $results = DB::table('test_table')->paginate(10);
                           /**       ^^^^^^^     */

        return  TestResource::collection($results);           
    }
```

Then in your Resource:

**Resources/Test.php**

```
class Test extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,  // <------
            'test_col' => $this->test_col,  // <------
        ];
    }
}
```